# How to make an event to give reactions in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create an event, which will be triggered when someone sends a message in a specific channel. In that message if the user mentions 4 users the bot would give a reaction onto his message.

I know I can give reaction with

```
await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji="<a:tick:748476262640779276>")
```

but I don't understand how can I create this kind of event. What function should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) event and [message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message.mentions) which will give you a list of members mentioned. you can just take the length of it.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if len(message.mentions) >= 4 and message.channel.id == 123456789:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji="<a:tick:748476262640779276>")

    await bot.process_commands(message) # to allow commands
```